# Baffled by the Arrow in Do Statements in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, memoization, state-monad

I am working on understanding the `State` monad and have written two simple versions of the famous fibonacci to memoize the function. The one with `let` in the body runs very slowly. The one with `<-` runs very fast. My question: Why? Is let causing full evaluation somehow while `<-` is allowing the `M.lookup` via `Data.Map` to work?

```
-- using state monad and let

-- very slow

fibLet :: Int -> State (M.Map Int Integer) Integer
fibLet n = do
   case n of 0 -> return 0
             1 -> return 1
             n -> do 
                  mp <- get
                  if M.member n mp 
                  then return $ fromJust (M.lookup n mp)
                  else do
                       let s1 = evalState (fibLet (n - 1)) mp                        
                       let s2 = evalState (fibLet (n - 2)) mp
                       let s3 = s1+s2
                       modify $ M.insert n s3
                       return s3


fibonacciLet :: Int -> Integer
fibonacciLet n = evalState (fibLet n) M.empty
```

```
-- using state monad and <-

-- very fast

fibArrow :: Int -> State (M.Map Int Integer) Integer
fibArrow n = do
    case n of 0 -> return 0
              1 -> return 1
              n -> do
                   mp <- get
                   if M.member n mp
                   then return $ fromJust (M.lookup n mp)
                   else do
                        s1 <-fibArrow (n - 1)
                        s2 <-fibArrow (n - 2)
                        let s3 = s1+s2
                        modify $ M.insert n s3
                        return s3


fibonacciArrow :: Int -> Integer
fibonacciArrow n = evalState (fibArrow n) M.empty
```

Comment: Is it deliberate that `fibArrow` calls `fibLet`, instead of recursing itself?

Comment: In the slow version, is it really `modify $ M.insert n s1`  ? I would have expected s3 not s1.

Comment: `evalState` throws away its state updates. When that state is your memoization table...

Comment: fixed the fibonacciArrow call. And use of s3 in fibLet. Slipped past me during edits. Thank you both for catching.

Answer (score 30):

`fibLet` isn't actually using its state very much at all! That's why it's so slow; it's essentially a very complicated way to write the classic Haskell fibonacci definition:

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

Look carefully what's going on here:

```
-- from earlier: mp <- get
do
   let s1 = evalState (fibLet (n - 1)) mp                        
   let s2 = evalState (fibLet (n - 2)) mp
   let s3 = s1+s2
   modify $ M.insert n s3
   return s3
```

`mp` is the `Map` of currently-known results. You use `evalState` to run `fibLet (n - 1)`, starting its state with `mp`. Then you use `evalState` again to run `fibLet (n - 2)`, starting its state with `mp` again. This means `fibLet (n - 1)` and `fibLet (n - 2)` aren't sharing any work; *each* of them is using the same starting map of already known results `mp`, so anything that isn't already in that map is going to have to be computed by both branches.

However it's actually *even worse* than that. Look at the type of `evalState`:

```
evalState :: State s a -> s -> a
```

It has no `State` in its return type. That means it isn't actually stateful. It does *not* interact with a any surrounding state; effectively it starts off a new state thread, runs it to completion<sup>1</sup>, after which the state is discarded.

You can tell that really easily by looking at the type of `evalState` slightly differently (but equivalently):

```
evalState :: State s a -> (s -> a)
```

`evalState` turns a `State s a` into a simple function typed `s -> a`. Obviously a plain old function can't alter the implicit state of a `do` block its called from (that's the whole point of making statefulness explicit in the types). So that means:

```
evalState (fibLet (n - 1)) :: M.Map Int Integer -> Integer
```

`evalState (fibLet (n - 1))` is just a plain old function from maps to integers. It neither accesses nor affects state of any kind.

So that means that after `let s1 = evalState (fibLet (n - 1)) mp` the state in the outer `do` block is still exactly equal to `mp`. **Nothing** has been saved in our state map of already computed results. So not only are we not sharing any work between the two separate recursive calls, they're not even sharing work within the deeper layers of recursion inside each call!

To prove it, try running `fibLet` using `runState` instead of `evalState`, so you can see what the final map is:

```
ghci> runState (fibLet 20) M.empty
(6765,fromList [(20,6765)])
it :: (Integer, M.Map Int Integer)
```

There's only a single entry in the map, added as the last step of the `do` block in the outermost call to `fibLet`, just before it returned.

If you do the same thing with `fibArrow` you get this:

```
ghci> runState (fibArrow 20) M.empty
(6765,fromList [(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,5),(6,8),(7,13),(8,21),(9,34),(10,55),(11,89),(12,144),(13,233),(14,377),(15,610),(16,987),(17,1597),(18,2584),(19,4181),(20,6765)])
it :: (Integer, M.Map Int Integer)
```

You can clearly see it's memoized all the intermediate results, not just the final one.

Bottom line: You don't usually want to use `evalState` (and similar functions like `runState` and `execState`) *inside* a function that's operating in the `State` monad. Those functions are intended for running the *whole* stateful computation, and so are normally run from "outside" a state monad context. When you happen to run them "inside" a state monad context, they do not interact with it; they instead receive (and return, in the case of `runState` and `execState`) state through ordinary argument passing and function return, not through the implicit state threading provided by `State`.

If you want to make a call to a "stateful sub-computation" (i.e. call a `State _ _` inside a function returning `State _ _`), then you need to bind the sub-computation as part of the outer one. The arrow statement inside `do` blocks does this; the `let` statement doesn't, it **only** gives a name to an ordinary expression. That's why you found yourself having to use `evalState` to get a result and explicitly feed `mp` even though you're already inside a stateful context where it should be available implicitly; the messiness of that was a hint that something wasn't right.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, it "runs it to completion" assuming that the result value is fully demanded.

Comment: Ben, that is an amazing, clear, and in depth answer. Thank you! Especially helpful is the general guidance about where to use evalState and runState.